# Woocommerce - redirect user to custom thank you page after an order is placed

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I need a bit of help with woocommerce customization. I need to redirect the user after the order is completed to a custom page, I'm using this code in my plugin but seems not working

```php
    public function redirect_customer_after_order()
    {
        if( is_checkout() && isset( $wp->query_vars['order-received'] ) ){
            wp_safe_redirect( site_url( 'riepilogo-ordine' ) );
            exit;
        }
    }
    add_action( 'template_redirect', array( $this, 'redirect_customer_after_order' ) );
```

I've tried to place an order but my custom woocommerce elementor page will be not displayed and I will see the default woocommerce thank you page. Also I've noticed that this hook will be ignored

```php
remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_details_after_order_table', 'woocommerce_order_again_button' );
```

It will simple remove the order again button, I've placed it inside the `__construct()` of my plugin. How I can fix these two issues?

Answer (score 2):

Please Try this code for redirect custom thank you page

```html
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'custom_thankyou_cb');
  function custom_thankyou_cb( $order_id ){
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $url = 'https://yoursite.com/custom-custom-thankyou-page';
    if ( ! $order->has_status( 'failed' ) ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( $url );
        exit;
    }
}
```

`

Comment: hello and welcome. I've seen this snippet on some sites, but what I need is to have the order recap in my custom page. At the moment the redirection seems working but I will see a blank page and the order details widget I've added using elementor will be not loaded

Comment: Hello, please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.